# TypeError: react_bootstrap__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Media is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typeerror, undefined, react-bootstrap

I've been recently working on creating a blog in react-bootstrap, and while almost every part of my code runs just fine, I can't pinpoint exactly why I am getting an error; I've narrowed it down to within this snippet of code. A type error is thrown where the compiler cannot read properties of undefined type within `'Media.Body'`. How can I fix this or make the type within the `Media.Body` component returnable? Any help would be appreciated; thanks!

```js
   import {  Row, Col, Image, Card, Media } from "react-bootstrap";
   <Media className="mb-4 admin-intro">
              <Image
                roundedCircle
                width={64}
                height={64}
                className="mr-3"
                src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/05/22/37/blank-profile-picture-973460__340.png"
                alt="Generic placeholder"
              />
              <Media.Body>
                <h5 className="font-weight-bold mb-0">Hello Friends,</h5>
                <p className="welcome-text">
                  My name is <irl name reveal> and I am a freelance developer. This is my blog page.
                </p>
              </Media.Body>
            </Media>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like react-bootstrap doesn't have Media component. I searched through react-bootstrap components and didn't find it. So, maybe you wanted to use Modal component instead?

Comment: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/figures/ would be more appropriate as it is an mage

Comment: Thanks for the help! Yeah I found out the problem; the Media component was deprecated and I'd need to downgrade to react-bootstrap@1.6.1

I could just use the Card component instead.

Comment: Can you please mark the question as solved?